# Python Dataframe Check All rows equal to False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has boolean values. I want to extract rows where all of them are False.

My code:

```
df = 
                               colA               colB
datetime                                            
2019-01-01 10:09:18            False             NaN
2019-01-01 10:10:55             True             NaN
2019-01-02 07:32:36             True            True
2019-01-02 13:32:29             True            True
2019-01-02 15:32:26             True           False
2020-17-23 18:44:45            False           False
2020-17-24 14:14:13             True            True
2020-17-24 18:44:44            False           False
2020-17-25 06:44:43            False           False
2020-17-25 14:14:13             True            True

# The following gives output True when all are True. I want True when all are False
print(df.all(1))
```

Present output:

```
datetime
2019-10-01 10:09:18    False
2019-10-01 10:10:55     True
2019-10-02 07:32:36     True
2019-10-02 13:32:29     True
2019-10-02 15:32:26     False
 
2020-07-23 18:44:45    False
2020-07-24 14:14:13     True
2020-07-24 18:44:44    False
2020-07-25 06:44:43    False
2020-07-25 14:14:13     True
```

The second row gives True for True and NaN, which is bad. It should actually give False here. The main thing I want to achieve is, True when all are False (not including NaNs)

Answer (score 1):

First `fillna` with `True`, then we use `all` over `axis=1` and finally invert our outcome with `~`:

```
~df.fillna(True).all(axis=1)

datetime
2019-01-01 10:09:18     True
2019-01-01 10:10:55    False
2019-01-02 07:32:36    False
2019-01-02 13:32:29    False
2019-01-02 15:32:26     True
2020-17-23 18:44:45     True
2020-17-24 14:14:13    False
2020-17-24 18:44:44     True
2020-17-25 06:44:43     True
2020-17-25 14:14:13    False
```

Comment: is this correct? `df[['colA','colB']].eq(False).all(1)`?